# x86 Android emulator not working on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, android-emulator, macos-sierra

I can't start the x86 Android emulator on macOS Sierra. When I run `android` the 'Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator' option is marked as not compatible with Mac OS X.

[image]

The accelerator seems to be available only up to version 10.11 according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager.

Does anybody know something about that issue or plans to support macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even on macOS Sierra, it is possible to install HAXM manually from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/ in version 6.0.3 which officially supports only up to Mac OS X El Capitan.

After that the emulator is fully functional.